# What are the advantages of having a aluminium frame?

Tags: frames, carbon, aluminum, framebuilding

are there any advantages that an aluminium body brings to the tables over carbon frames?

Comment: I've edited your question to remove superfluous information. Feel free to revert if you disagree with my edits

Comment: Aluminum is cheap, which I suspect is the prime motivator from a manufacturer perspective.  While there is steel and titanium out there, I suspect that steel and ti are principally the domain of local bike builders and not gigantic conglomerate that also happen to make bikes.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you mean "apart from price"?

The other important differences are:

1. Lightness: Carbon is generally lighter, but not always.  It is possible to buy alu frames that are lighter than some carbon frames.
2. Comfort: Generally, alu bikes are stiffer and less comfortable than carbon bikes.
3. Strength: Simply, metal bends and carbon breaks, but both can be repaired equally successfully these days!
4. Price!!  Generally, like for like carbon frames will be more expensive.

The real questions is "will a carbon bike make a difference to YOU".

Comment: It should be pointed out that aluminum fatigues, far worse than steel, and likely worse than carbon.

Answer (score 0):

Well it is not depend of diameter of the wheels there is more variables to consider. Sames goes for the frame. There is high quality aluminium frames which are better that low quality "cheap" carbon (cheapest carbon frame bike perfectly can go up to 1000$).

Over all carbon beats aluminium it is lighter it stronger it more shock absorbent. But it far more expensive and it's more fragile. It you must be more careful in not hitting the frame.

There is different covers for frames. In mountain even small stones hits can damage the frame over time and make it fail over a big stress.

EDIT: I found a related question: [What are the pros and cons between an aluminium and carbon frame?](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/19085/what-are-the-pros-and-cons-between-an-aluminium-and-carbon-frame)